# Chromedriver: How to get the network response values in a web page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So i want to obtain the values from Web page Inspect-> Network

Specifically I want to get login->Response->token value

Is there a python Chromedriver way to get this?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the performance stats using

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
s = Service(chrome_path)

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, service=s)
driver.get('https://www.zomato.com/bangalore')
perf = driver.get_log('performance')
```

perf is a list of dictionaries and you'll be able to find the item you're looking for in this list. i.e, dictionaries are the things that you see in Chrome's dev tool network tab.

Over there you will get everything including the url, request, response, XHR calls made with payload etc.

You can also use window.performance methods.

```
driver
  .executeScript( "return window.performance.getEntriesByType('resource');" )
  .then( (perfEntries)=> {
    let gaCalls = perfEntries.filter(function(entry){
      return /collect\?/i.test(entry.name);
    });
    console.log(gaCalls);
});
```